# show that $ \langle tTy- Tx,ty\rangle \geq 0$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

let $x,y\in H$ such that $H$ is a hilbert space such that $\langle Tu,u\rangle\geq 0$
let $x\in Im(T)^\perp$  show that $\forall t\in \mathbb R$ we have $ \langle tTy- Tx,ty\rangle \geq 0$.
My attempt:
we have that $x\in Im(T)^\perp$ so there exists $y$ such that $\langle Ty,x\rangle=0$.
but since $\langle Tu,u\rangle\geq 0$ then $\langle T(ty),ty \rangle\geq 0$ implies  $\langle tTy,ty \rangle\geq 0$  if i can prove that $\langle Tx,ty \rangle=0$ I can subtract it with previous statement to conclude the result but how?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement $x\in \mathrm{Im}(T)^\perp$ means that $\langle Ty, x\rangle = 0$ for all $y\in H$. By this statement we have $\langle tTy, x\rangle = \langle T(ty), x\rangle =0$ for any $y\in H$ and any $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Using this fact and properties of the inner product, we obtain
\begin{align*}\langle tTy - Tx, ty\rangle &= \langle T(ty -x), ty\rangle \\ &= \langle T(ty -x), ty\rangle - \langle T(ty-x), x\rangle  \\ 
&= \langle T(ty -x), (ty-x)\rangle
\end{align*}
Since $\langle Tu,u\rangle \geq 0$ for all $u \in H$ and $ty-x \in H$, we conclude that
$$
\langle tTy - Tx, ty\rangle = \langle T(ty -x), (ty-x)\rangle \geq 0.
$$